# Is there a limit to how many times FBML.XFBML.parse() can be called per page?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following code to dynamically load a XFBML fragment into an Facebook IFRAME application.

The HTML:

```
<div id="fragment" style="display:none">
<fb:serverfbml id="fragmentfbml">
</fb:serverfbml>
```

The jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadFragment()
{
    jQuery.ajax(
    { 
        url: "xfbml_fragment.php", // contains the 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: "false",
        success: function (data)
        {
            jQuery("#fragmentfbml").html(data);
            FB.XFBML.parse();
            jQuery("#fragment").css("display","block");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The jQuery AJAX call works every time but the FB.XFBML.parse() call only works once. I've added a callback to FB.XFBML.parse() with console.log() (see below) and verified that it only executes the first time it's called.

```
FB.XFBML.parse(
   document.getElementbyId("fragment"),
   function( { console.log("parse called"); } )
);
```

Is this a known behaviour of FB.XFBML.parse() (certainly doesn't say so in the [FB Javascript SDK docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse)) or am I just doing things wrongly here?

Comment: Have you tried FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fragmentfbml'))?

Comment: Yup, just tried that. Doesn't work either. Thanks for the suggestion though, didn't think of that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following function and was able to call FB.XFBML.parse() multiple times:

```
function createFbmlNode() {
   var like = document.createElement("fb:like");
   like.setAttribute('href', 'URL_TO_LIKE');
   like.setAttribute('send', false);
   like.setAttribute('width', 450);
   like.setAttribute('show_faces', false);

   document.getElementById('response').appendChild(like);

   FB.XFBML.parse(); 
}
```

The Node is created in the following span:

`<span id="response" style="display: block;"></span>`

The like button iFrame is created from the parse method.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around we can try removing and reinserting the connect js before recalling the parse function. The parse function works once everytime we insert the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Note**

> FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no
>   longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed.

[fb:serverFbml](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml/) is part of FBML

Comment: xfbml is javascript sdk, fbml was server side api.

Comment: @ShawnECarter If you had bothered *clicking* the link in my answer you would have noticed that Facebook states that *FBML has been deprecated*. I wasn't the one who wrote it, Facebook did.
also, the title of this question is "FBML.XFBML.parse()" which led me to tell him it was deprecated !

Thanks for the unhelpful down vote.

FYI. he is trying to parse fb:serverFBML using xfbml Javascript API, which would have workd, 6 months ago, maybe.

Answer (score -2):

I can verify that FB.XFBML.parse() used to work.
i.e. you could call it as many times as you wanted
however Facebook recently broke it. Now you can only
call it once.

Comment: Facebook did not break it, it is part of the Platform Roadmap, and FBML deprecation was announced more then 90 days ago.

Comment: i use xfbml.parse in every app i own, fbml was a server side api.